# Getting multiple UITableViews in the same view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two UITableViews named TableView1 and TableView2 in the same view, and I'm having trouble populating them. I've used some suggestions in other SO questions, but I haven't been able to get them to work (see description below). In my code, I've set weak outlets in the relevant .m file as follows:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;
```

Then, in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `NumberOfRowsInSection`, `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I've put in code similar to the following. It is worth noting that tableView1 is grouped and tableView2 is plain, so there are additional header-related methods (for tableView2) and a method for section title for tableView1 that I have not put in these checks for, since they can only be called by one table view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        // stuff for tableView1;
    } else {
        // stuff for tableView2;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this gives the result of only displaying the second table view. As per other SO posts, I've also tried the tag method by setting

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.tableView1.tag = 33;
    self.tableView2.tag = 34;
    ...
}
```

...and NSLog confirms that the tags are being set correctly, and I know that these tags aren't used anywhere else in the storyboard. After replacing all the `if (tableView == self.tableView1)` checks with `if (tableView.tag == 33)`, the first table view still did not show up when run. I logged the tag of the tableView in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and discovered that `tableView.tag` was always 34, even though I had specifically set `tableView1.tag` to be 33.

EDIT: Making sure the `delegate` and `dataSource` for both table views are set (thanks to commenters) now logs tags of both 33 and 34, as desired, but the first table view is still not appearing.

Is there an obvious reason I'm missing as to why neither of these two methods are working? Or is there a more efficient way to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the data source for `tableView1`?  Can you log delegate and data source values in `viewDidLoad` to be sure of the setup?

Comment: Are your `delegate` and `dataSource` set for _both_ table views?

Comment: The `delegate` and `dataSource` for `tableView2` were set to `self` (i.e. the view controller), but they had not been set for `tableView1`. Setting both for `tableView1` to `self` solves the issue with the tag always being 34, but the issue with `tableView1` not appearing on the screen still persists.

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath are you sure it is being called for tableview1 and tableview2? is there any possibility that tableview1 is being covered by another object? in viewDidAppear NSLog the number of rows of tableview1 to make sure it was actually has some rows to display

Comment: The number of sections and rows were both nonzero. Redoing my constraints entirely has allowed `tableView1` to appear, however, so it appears as if this problem is resolved. Thanks to all for the suggestions!